# How can I stop vim from editing directories?

Tags: shell, vim

Sometimes I accidentally tell vim to edit a directory instead of a file in it

```
vim directory-name           # what I typed
vim directory-name/blah.txt  # what I meant to type
```

Instead of immediately giving an error message, vim will open the directory in a "file editor" mode that I personally don't like:

[image: The file browser I don't like]

**How can I make vim refuse to open directories instead?**

One possible avenue could be by changing some settings in my .vimrc but I don't know what they would be.

Another possibility would be to create a wrapper shell alias around vim that checks with something along the lines of `test -d "$1"` to see if I'm trying to open a file. However, I don't know to make this alias robust so that it can tell apart which command-line arguments are flags and which are file names.

Comment: `vim` doesn't edit directories. It discovers that your argument is a directory it gives you the choice to select one of the files within that directory. You may be incompatible to `vim`, so choose a different editor or help yourself with a shell function that checks if your argument is a file or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the following lines in your vimrc to quit vim if any of its arguments are a directory:

```bsh
for f in argv()
  if isdirectory(f)
    echomsg "vimrc: Cowardly refusing to edit directory " . f
    quit
  endif
endfor
```

Alternatively, if you only want to quit if *all* arguments are directories, you can try something like this:

```bsh
let ndirs = 0
for f in argv()
  if isdirectory(f)
    let ndirs += 1
  endif
endfor
if ndirs > 0 && ndirs == argc()
  echomsg "vimrc: Cowardly refusing to edit directories"
  quit
endif
```

Comment: I think it would be more natural to do this kind of thing as a shell script wouldn't it?

Comment: @hugomg not really, `vim` code will be more portable, and `vim` should know its arguments while under `{bash,csh,fish,ksh,tcsh,zsh,$other}` you'd (ideally) need to distinguish between file arguments and options and arguments to options, which could introduce false positives.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that argv() didn't include the flags! Before I accept this, what is that "whoops, more things to edit" case that you are working around?

Comment: @hugomg try `vim file /etc` or `vim /etc file` instead of just the simple `vim file` or `vim /etc`

Comment: I had to make some changes to get everything to work. First of all, your original code was buggy with multiple files (ex.: `vim /etc /etc`). Secondly, the echomsg would only appear to the shell that invoked vim if I put the commands directly in the vimrc, outside the `QuitIfDirectory`  function.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the output of the `netrw` plugin.

This can be disabled by entering in your `~/.vimrc` file.

```
let loaded_netrwPlugin = 1
```

Now if you try and edit a directory you'll get an error `is a directory`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still causes vim to open a new window so its not much better than before...